# Calculate lines (elements) and set a value to a field with calculated column

Tags: 2010, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a list with some columns, among these columns there is one named "palette".
I would like to count the number of elements in the list, and put the value "1" for the ten first elements at the "palette" field. Then "2" for the 10 next elements...

I think calculated column should be a good way to do that, but I don't understand how to do this.

EXAMPLE :

My list :

[image]

For example, I want the three first lines to be at 1 in Palette field, then 2 for the three next, then 3, ... automatically

Comment: Can you put an example of the input and the expected result ?

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint item IDs.

Your calculated column would look like this:

```
=([ID-1]/3)+1
```

Example:

```
ID      RESULT
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         2
6         2
7         3
8         3
9         3
10        4
...       ...
```

The problem with this is that it has to be a fresh list to start from ID value 1. (for example if you had 20 items in a list and you deleted them, when you will create new item it's ID will be 21, even though the list is empty)

Also, take a look at [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: yeah good idea but as you said it's not working dynamically